Ubuntu 24.04 installed gnuplot does not work
If I try to use gnuplot in Ubuntu 24.04 I got the message
gnuplot: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5)
gnuplot: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5)
(I did not install Qt6) In Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04 I found that the link
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.13 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
helps (I guess this is not correct) and gnuplot works but now with 24.04
the error message will not disappear. Could you please give me some help to change this?

That sounds like you have not installed gnuplot correctly.  Did you following the following installation instructions? https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-24-04/package/gnuplot  (That will give you 'sudo apt install gnuplot-qt'   # version 5.4.4+dfsg1-2build1

Can you share more details about how are you trying to use gnoplot? Can you share some code maybe that we can use to reproduce the issue?

@david : I removed gnuplot and reinstalled it again by the commands mentioned in linux-packages/... but the error messages after the interactive command gnuplot  (@Archisman Panigrahi) remaines.

How is Ubuntu installed? Do you have it installed on Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL)?

Ubuntu 24.04 is installed with 22.04 by the actualization window which pops up in 22.04.

I looked on my system and the there is an addition link as follows: -
'sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.13 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15' (You probably have to set permission 'sudo chmod 777  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15' Alternatively might like to reinstall this library as I think they need to be registered as well as linked. 'sudo apt-get reinstall libqt5core5t64' All this may well be risky so AT OWN RISK.

This is a link which I use with Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 and gnuplot is working but now with 24.04 this is no more the case. Thanks for your answer.

@Archisman Panigrahi : I use a terminal with the '/bin/bash' - Shell. Therein I typed 'gnuplot' and got immediately the error message mentioned above.

That link (my previous posting) is not the same as your described in your question. The one you describe ends in .so.5 and the one I have added ends in .so.5.15 which, incidentally, forms part of the error message you were getting.

@David : I wrote that I changed the link to the version you mentioned (removed the other link) but the error message is the same. The questions are 1.why uses gnuplot a library which is not installed in the Qt environment, 2. why gnuplot works in your installation of Ubuntu 24.04 and not in the brand new installation (nothing changed except the link mentioned by you) by me.

My rig has both links (.so.5.15 and .so.5 ). I have not added any links. They are part of the install of the library. Mine was a new/clean install. Can you append to you question the result of 'ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'

It's a too long list and to append files to comments is not allowed. I'm a new contributor so chats are not allowed for me.

The problem is solved. I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on an other computer and have to change several links on the first machine. Then it works on the first machine. Thank you for your help. I don't know how to close this question as solved.
